# TypeError: Input data can not be a list

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to create a health status prediction ml project with python, i used XGBoost algorithm, but i'm getting an error

```
TypeError: Input data can not be a list.
```

in  `model.predict([[13,35,20,29,18,20,31,41,22,22,0]])` below. What should I do to fix this?

My code:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

model.predict([[13,35,20,29,18,20,31,41,22,22,0]])
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636775/input-data-cannot-be-a-list-xgboost

Comment: @navneethc Yeah, i've already seen this question, but i got another error when i tried this solution. It does not fix my problem.

Comment: Please *explain* how the solution there did not work, otherwise it looks indeed as a duplicate. Plus, please do not post here code irrelevant to the actual issue - SO code is supposed to be *minimal* (edited).